# Flutter App working on Simulator but not working on ios real device

Tags: iphone, flutter, file, exception, error-handling

```
DioException [unknown): null
Error: PathAccessException: Creation failed, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/31ED4B1D-090A-47A0-A521-D95028D7C599/Documentsie0_ps1/' (OS Error:
Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

This error is showing in real device.Please help me

Comment: When the system tells you to add more information, add something helpful instead of just pasting the same poorly formatted question. Add enough details that others can reproduce the problem; see [ask].